# String replaceAll multiple characters

Tags: java, regex, string

Without replaceall Output: `[3, 2, 1]`

With replaceall Output: `3,2,1`

Is there anyway to do this using single replaceAll method, something like

```
      set.toString().replaceAll("\\[\\]\\s+","");
```

Now Code

```
      Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();    
      set.add("1");
      set.add("2");
      set.add("3");
      System.out.println(set.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [Guava's `Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
String joined = Joiner.on(",").join(set);
System.out.println(joined);  // 1,2,3
```

Or, if you can't use any 3rd party library, then following `replaceAll` would work:

```
System.out.println(set.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]|(?<=,)\\s+", ""));  // 1,2,3
```

Well, you won't get always the same output, as `HashSet` doesn't preserve insertion order. If you want that, use `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: I knew it Jain thing want for is how to replace multiple regex with single replace all method, GOT IT .Thank you.

Comment: @sunleo. You can always merge multiple regex using alternation - `|`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using this regex, `[\\[\\]]`.

```
System.out.println(set.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")); // Output is 3,2,1
```

If you want to remove the white space also, then use this regex, `[\\[\\]\\s]` (but the comma will be there).

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll("[^\\d|,]", "");` will replace everything that is not a digit (`\\d`) or (`|`) a comma (`,`). The hat symbol `^` means not in Java regex and the square brackets `[]` denote a set. So our set is "everything that is not a digit or a comma".

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("1");
set.add("2");
set.add("3");
System.out.println(set.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d|,]", ""));
```

Output:

`3,2,1`